# Spring security exception handler

Tags: spring, exception, logging, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have spring oauth2 authorization server with authorization_code and refresh_token grant types client. Sometimes it happens that used refresh_token is not valid, which causes long and ugly exception in logs:

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.exceptions.InvalidGrantException: Invalid refresh token: xxxxxxxx-yyyy-xxxx-yyyy-xxxxxxxxxxxx
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices.refreshAccessToken(DefaultTokenServices.java:142) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.refresh.RefreshTokenGranter.getAccessToken(RefreshTokenGranter.java:47) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.AbstractTokenGranter.grant(AbstractTokenGranter.java:65) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.CompositeTokenGranter.grant(CompositeTokenGranter.java:38) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
[...]
```

Is it there anything like `@RestControllerAdvice` which would handle such exceptions?
I already tried using mentioned `@RestControllerAdvice`, but unfortunately it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiarized with *Spring OAUTH2 Authorization*, however my answer might be helpful for you.

`@RestControllerAdvice` is designed to assist `@RestController` therefore it works if the request is handled by the DispatcherServlet. However, security-related exceptions occurs before that as it is thrown by Filters. Hence, it is required to insert a custom filter [AccessDeniedHandler implementation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/AccessDeniedHandler.html) and [AuthenticationEntryPoint implementation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/AuthenticationEntryPoint.html)) earlier in the chain to catch the exception and return accordingly. These filters can be inserted easily in your web security configurations.

Here you can learn how to [detect an Authentication Failure in the Client](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/#_social_login_custom_error).

You could also check this [tutorial](http://javabycode.com/spring-framework-tutorial/spring-security/secure-spring-rest-api-using-spring-security-oauth2-example.html) .